# Delete older versions in a library that have a date suffix older than today's sysdate

Tags: sas

I am totally new to SAS but have been tasked with cleaning up one of our SAS processes.

We have a SAS Library which has a number of versions of a table which have a date suffix.

For example: COL_DATA_TABLE_2022_02_15

Due that our update creates one of these every time the process is run, I would like to delete all that do not equal the one I am creating when the process runs.
The process runs infrequently. So there could be days when the process is not run.

Code creating the new version:

```
proc datasets lib=Lib1 nolist ;
 change COL_DATA_TABLE = COL_DATA_TABLE_&sysdate. ;
quit ;
```

What code should I use to remove the previous versions of the table? As they are out of date, taking into account that the date suffix could be any date.

For those in the library now, I will delete them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would deleting all the COL_DATA_TABLE_: tables before the CHANGE work?

```
proc datasets lib=Lib1 nolist ;
   delete COL_DATA_TABLE_:; *note name with _:;
   run;
   change COL_DATA_TABLE = COL_DATA_TABLE_&sysdate. ;
   quit;
```